# Как через Ajax/XMLHttpRequest получить определенный объект из JSON?

Tags: javascript, json, xml, xmlhttprequest

Имеется функция, которая посылает Ajax запрос к JSON файлу за контентом, парсит, компилирует с Handlebars Template и помещает в нужный div на html страницу. Как "научить" ее брать не весь контент JSON файла, а только определенный объект/массив или элемент объекта/массива (чтобы затем можно было заменить эту часть кода переменной, которую задавать при вызове функции)?

Ajax и XMLHttpRequest только начал изучать, буду рад совету.

Вот функция (оформлена как commonjs модуль):

```js
module.exports = function(jsonDir, templId, finId){
function sendGet(callback) {
    /* create an AJAX request using XMLHttpRequest*/
    var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
    

    /* Specify the type of request by using XMLHttpRequest "open", 
       here 'GET'(argument one) refers to request type
       "jsonDir" (argument two) refers to JSON file location*/
    xhr.open('GET', jsonDir);

    /*Using onload event handler you can check status of your request*/
    xhr.onload = function () {
        if (xhr.status === 200) {
            callback(JSON.parse(xhr.responseText));
        } else {
            alert(xhr.statusText);
        }
    };

    /*Using onerror event handler you can check error state, if your request failed to get the data*/
    xhr.onerror = function () {
        alert("Network Error");
    };

    /*send the request to server*/
    xhr.send();
}

//For template-1
var dateTemplate = document.getElementById(templId).innerHTML;
var template = Handlebars.compile(dateTemplate);

sendGet(function (response) {
    document.getElementById(finId).innerHTML += template(response);
})
}
```

Comment: Если вы используете на стороне сервера asp.net или аналог, то вы можете обработать (вырезать нужный кусок) требуемый файл на сервере и отправить результат клиенту. Иначе вы в любом случае получите целый файл и выбирать нужный кусок придется уже на клиенте после `JSON.parse(xhr.responseText))`.

Comment: @AndrewB Я использую NodeJS, в этом случае это можно сделать на сервере?А если обрабатывать на клиенте, правильно ли я понимаю что после `JSON.parse(xhr.responseText))` переменная xhr хранит в себе JSON контент, преобразованный в JS формат, и теперь можно обратиться, например, к нужному объекту или массиву через `xhr.objectName.propertyName`?

Comment: С nodejs не знаком, если он позволяет создавать обработчики для запросов и работать с файлами, то проблем быть не должно. Просто ловите нужный запрос и делаете ответ который вам нужен. На клиенте после `var resp = JSON.parse(response);` вы получаете готовый объект, с которым можете работать как с любым другим js объектом `var x = resp.setting1 || "default";`

Comment: @AndrewB Извините, не понял ваш последний пример, вернее его вторую часть. В первой вы обращаетесь к ключу или парамтру js объекта, а ИЛИ "default" - значение, которое подставляется если такого элемента нет? Чему равно "default"?

Comment: Это просто для примера. Взять значение из setting1 если оно есть иначе записать строку "default". При такой проверке `пустая строка, null, undefined, 0, false` ее не пройдут (вместо них будет использоваться строка после `||`). Это не очень хороший способ из-за особенностей, зато короткий.